# How to include hidapi in makefile?

Tags: c++, makefile, g++, fedora

how should properly include HIDAPI library?. After installing from the Fedora 20 repositories. It is installed in `/usr/lib`

This is my makefile:

```
CC=g++
CCFLAGS= -Wall -O0
SOURCE= Main.cpp ModuloUsb.cpp ModuloUsb.h
EXEC=modulo
test:$(SOURCE)
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) $(SOURCE) -I../hidapi  `pkg-config --libs --cflags libusb-1.0`  -o $(EXEC)
```

After make command: 
[image]
Any suggestions??

Comment: What isn't working here? What error are you getting? Is `../hidapi` where the header files list? Is `pkg-config` returning all the `-l` flags you need?

Comment: He says he does not find the file, hidapi.h, so I doubt that my line is well written which should include the library

Comment: Where is the header file installed? How did you install `hidapi`? Did you install it from a package? If so did you install the `-devel` package to go along with it?

Comment: I have not installed the -devel, now install and communicate, thanks for your response

Comment: I have installed -devel and not work

Comment: *What* isn't working? Be specific. Include specific error messages in the post.